# warning when using BOOL variable in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, boolean

I am trying to initalize my BOOL variable to YES but its giving me this warning.. not quite sure what to do.. it still seems to be working fine but just wondering how I can get rid of the warning.

I have initalize the variable in the header like this

//.h

```
BOOL *removeActivityIndicator;
//..
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL *removeActivityIndicator;
```

Then I try to set it to YES like so (this is also where I get the warning)

```
self.removeActivityIndicator = YES;
```

The warning says :

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'BOOL' (aka
>   'signed char') to paramater of type 'BOOL *' (aka 'signed char *')

Comment: Now you have an answer, do you see that the warning is telling you exactly what is going wrong? It's expecting a 'BOOL *' and you are passing a 'BOOL'?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The warning is correct; you've declared the variable as a `BOOL *` (a pointer to a BOOL), which is almost certainly not what you want. Remove the `*` from the declaration.

Answer (score 4):

`removeActivityIndicator` is a char **pointer**, and you assigns a char to it, so either:

1. change it to be `BOOL removeActivityIndicator;`
2. Dereference it: `*(self.removeActivityIndicator) = YES;`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "char pointer". It's just a pointer.

Comment: I mean a pointer to a char, it is important to what type of variable it points to.

Comment: Actually, a BOOL is an signed char, which is `char`

Answer (score 3):

You've made a pointer to a `BOOL`, which is a primitive type. Remove the extra `*` in front of `remoteActivityIndicator`.